# When using the Quickbooks API explorer, read a vendor endpoint returns additional fields. How do I get these fields in actual API results?

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Response from API via API explorer(by Intuit)

```
{
 "Vendor": {
  "BillAddr": {
   "Id": "9",
   "Line1": "31/2-34/2B, G01, Ground Floor (P V Enclave, V-Step Road)",
   "Line2": "Kempapura",
   "City": "Bangalore",
   "Country": "India",
   "CountrySubDivisionCode": "karnataka",
   "PostalCode": "560037"
  },
  "BusinessNumber": "ABPFA3772K",
  "Balance": 12960,
  "BillRate": 0,
  "Vendor1099": false,
  "CurrencyRef": {
   "value": "INR",
   "name": "Indian Rupee"
  },
  "TDSEnabled": true,
  "TDSEntityTypeId": 2,
  "TDSSectionTypeId": 20,
  "TDSOverrideThreshold": false,
  "GSTIN": "29ABPFA3772K1ZT",
  "GSTRegistrationType": "GST_REG_REG",
  "CostRate": 0,
  "domain": "QBO",
  "sparse": false,
  "Id": "5",
  "SyncToken": "3",
  "MetaData": {
   "CreateTime": "2021-11-29T04:13:02-08:00",
   "LastUpdatedTime": "2022-06-19T11:18:01-07:00"
  },
  "CompanyName": "Asyncauto",
  "DisplayName": "Asyncauto",
  "PrintOnCheckName": "Asyncauto",
  "Active": true,
  "V4IDPseudonym": "002085e0c7fca007484293913d58943f84b215",
  "PrimaryPhone": {
   "FreeFormNumber": "1231231234"
  },
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
   "Address": "123123@mralbert.in"
  }
 },
 "time": "2022-06-19T19:00:23.349-07:00"
}
```

Response from the actual API endpoint (quickbooks.api.intuit.com)

```
{
    "Vendor": {
        "BillAddr": {
            "Id": "9",
            "Line1": "31/2-34/2B, G01, Ground Floor (P V Enclave, V-Step Road)",
            "Line2": "Kempapura",
            "City": "Bangalore",
            "Country": "India",
            "CountrySubDivisionCode": "karnataka",
            "PostalCode": "560037"
        },
        "BusinessNumber": "ABPFA3772K",
        "Balance": 12960.00,
        "Vendor1099": false,
        "CurrencyRef": {
            "value": "INR",
            "name": "Indian Rupee"
        },
        "domain": "QBO",
        "sparse": false,
        "Id": "5",
        "SyncToken": "3",
        "MetaData": {
            "CreateTime": "2021-11-29T04:13:02-08:00",
            "LastUpdatedTime": "2022-06-19T11:18:01-07:00"
        },
        "CompanyName": "Asyncauto",
        "DisplayName": "Asyncauto",
        "PrintOnCheckName": "Asyncauto",
        "Active": true,
        "PrimaryPhone": {
            "FreeFormNumber": "1231231234"
        },
        "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
            "Address": "123123@mralbert.in"
        }
    },
    "time": "2022-06-19T19:04:59.703-07:00"
}
```

Notice that in the second case these fields - "TDSEnabled","TDSEntityTypeId","TDSSectionTypeId","TDSOverrideThreshold","GSTIN","GSTRegistrationType", are missing.

How do I get these fields in the regular production endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Postman and see if issue persist then you need to talk with quickbooks support.

I have found that in indian edition of quickbooks still has many issue open.

Comment: tried using postman. The issue persists. Will try talking to support. Thanks for the lead.